# Sum of specific property values

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to see if there's a way that I can in Cypher do a sum of all stats in nodes (so including all types and categories, where there can be many).  Or at the users request exclude some such as excluding all of category1 or just excluding category1, type3.

Hopefully I explained it correctly but I'm not even sure if this is possible.

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide more info on how these categories and types are represented in your graph structure. Are these properties of certain nodes? Labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can do this.  Imagine two `Foo` nodes with those properties.  One limitation here is that we need to store that total on the node, like this:

```
create (a:Foo { type1: 3, type2: 4, type3: 7, total: 0 });
create (b:Foo { type1: 1, type2: 3, type4: 4, total: 0 });
```

Now if we want to sum those properties:

```
MATCH (a:Foo) 
  FOREACH (prop in 
    filter(z in keys(a) WHERE z <> 'total') | 
  SET a.total = a.total + a[prop]);
```

Breaking down what this does, the `keys` function iterates over all of the properties in a node.  Here we're going through all of the properties *except* the `total` property.   For each property, we're just adding its value to the total.  Viola.

Supposing you wanted a different set of properties and not *all* of them, you'd just adjust the `WHERE z<> 'total'` part to pick out the ones you want, like `WHERE z = 'something' or z = 'something else'`

Finally:

```
MATCH (a:Foo) RETURN a.total;
+---------+
| a.total |
+---------+
| 14      |
| 8       |
+---------+
```